# Create custom model (formula) in R

Tags: r, regression, self-study

Let's say I want to check how my data compares to a well-known regression model. How do I create a model object so I can use it in `predict()`?
For example I want to create such regression model with given coefficients $y=5x_1+12x_2+2$. I want to have an object identical to the one that is returned by `lm()` etc.

Comment: The question is obviously off-topic here (might be on topic at StackOverflow), but why do you want a `lm` object? You can write your own function to obtain predictions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `offset()` to do that. For example,

```
# simulate some data
DF <- data.frame(x1 = runif(100, -3, 3), x2 = runif(100, -3, 3))
DF$y <- 2 + 5 * DF$x1 + 12 * DF$x2 + rnorm(100, sd = 2)

# a model in which we estimate the coefficients
fm1 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = DF)

# here we use offset() to fix the coefficients
fm2 <- lm(y ~ 0 + offset(5 * x1) + offset(12 * x2) + offset(2 * rep(1, length(x1))), 
          data = DF)

# new data for prediciton
new_DF <- data.frame(x1 = runif(10, -3, 3), x2 = runif(10, -3, 3))

# predictions from the two model
predict(fm1, newdata = new_DF)
predict(fm2, newdata = new_DF)

# double-check the predictions from fm2 are according to
# the formula
2 + 5 * new_DF$x1 + 12 * new_DF$x2
```